# what is the reason of the null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, button

hi all i try to do calculator,i'm write the following code and when i try to run it i have a null pointer exception i don't know what is the error ,i found that my code is good and no error the function goes in force close before the layout appear and every thing inside onclickerlistener so at least i must goes in force close when i clicked on any button if there is something wrong please help me 
this is my code:

```
    package com.example.calculato;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

         EditText edt;

            double  num1=0,num2=0,result=0;
            double fact=1;

            String a="";
            char  op;
            boolean b=false;
            Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b12,b13,b14,b15,b16,b17,b18,b19,b20,b21;  

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Log.d("inside on create ", "okzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz");
            edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
             b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
             b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
             b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
             b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
             b5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
             b6=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
             b7=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);
             b8=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
             b9=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);
             b10=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button10);
             b11=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button11);
             b12=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button12);
             b13=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button13);
             b14=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button14);
             b15=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button15);
             b16=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button16);
             Log.d("after def  ", "okzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz");
             b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        a=edt.getText().toString();
                          edt.setText(a+ "1");

                    }
                });

              b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        a=edt.getText().toString();
                          edt.setText(a+ "2");

                    }
                });

              b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        a=edt.getText().toString();
                          edt.setText(a+ "3");

                    }
                });

              b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        a=edt.getText().toString();
                          edt.setText(a+ "4");  
                    }
                });
              b5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        a=edt.getText().toString();
                          edt.setText(a+ "5");

                    }
                });
              b6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        a=edt.getText().toString();
                          edt.setText(a+ "6");

                    }
                });

              b7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        a=edt.getText().toString();
                          edt.setText(a+ "7");

                    }
                });

              b8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        a=edt.getText().toString();
                          edt.setText(a+ "8");


                    }
                });
              b9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        a=edt.getText().toString();
                          edt.setText(a+ "9");

                    }
                });
              b10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        a=edt.getText().toString();
                          edt.setText(a+ "0");  
                    }
                });

              b13.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        num1=Double.valueOf(edt.getText().toString());
                        op='+';
                        edt.setText("");




                    }
                });
              b14.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         num1=Double.valueOf(edt.getText().toString());
                        op='-';
                        edt.setText("");


                    }
                });
              b15.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         num1=Double.valueOf(edt.getText().toString());
                        op='*';
                        edt.setText("");


                    }
                });
              b16.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         num1=Double.valueOf(edt.getText().toString());
                        op='/';
                        edt.setText("");


                    }
                });
              b11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        edt.setText(" ");




                    }
                });



                 b12.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        try {
                            String Value = edt.getText().toString();
                            if(Value.length()==1)
                                edt.setText("");
                            else 
                            {
                            Value = Value.substring(0,Value.length()-1);
                            edt.setText(Value);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }

                    }
                });
                 b17.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                             num2=Double.valueOf(edt.getText().toString());

                            if(op=='+')
                            {
                                result=num1+num2;
                                 edt.setText(String.valueOf(result));

                            }
                            if(op=='-')
                            {
                                result=num1-num2;
                                 edt.setText(String.valueOf(result));

                            }
                            if(op=='*')
                            {
                                result=num1*num2;
                                 edt.setText(String.valueOf(result));

                            }
                            if(op=='/')
                                {

                                if(num2!=0)
                                {
                                    result=num1/num2;
                                     edt.setText(String.valueOf(result));
                                    }
                                else
                                    edt.setText("Math Error");
                                }

                        }
                    });

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
```

And this the logcat :

```
            10-28 14:16:22.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1049): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-28 14:16:22.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1049): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.calculato/com.example.calculato.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    10-28 14:16:22.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
    10-28 14:16:22.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    10-28 14:16:22.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    10-28 14:16:22.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    10-28 14:16:22.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    10-28 14:16:22.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    10-28 14:16:22.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
    10-28 14:16:22.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-28 14:16:22.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    10-28 14:16:22.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    10-28 14:16:22.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    10-28 14:16:22.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    10-28 14:16:22.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1049): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    10-28 14:16:22.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.example.calculato.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:254)
    10-28 14:16:22.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    10-28 14:16:22.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    10-28 14:16:22.488: E/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

Comment: add the stacktrace you get

Comment: I think you need some sauce with that spaghetti, you can't find a way to loop it?

Comment: post your logcat sir , I'll give you a hint , see logcat , search for the name of your current class , see the line number , go to the line number , whichever element it is , just initialize that

Comment: @bessan can you please give stacktrace indicating which line of code throws an NPE ?

Comment: I see your activity implements OnClickListener, and then for each button you create a new object that implements OnClickListener? what you really need is to read a little more about java.

Comment: Warlock:i wasn't in my code but when i faced this problem i just try it ,event that the application doesn't run anymore

Comment: and pleeeaaaase use punctuation to end your sentences. For other non-native-english-speakers, it's hard to read your english if you don't use punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

hope this can help you: b17 is not initialized

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
b17.setOnClickListener(
```

`b17` is null, so you get `NullPointerException`. Always read your LogCat very carefully, it's all there.

Answer (score 1):

First initilize button17 like this

```
 b17=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button17);
```

Then set Click listener.
Like

```
b17.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 ---
 ---
 ---
 }
```

Enjoy...

Answer (score 0):

you didn't initialized the `Button` b17 ... 
Following your logic , you should write `b17=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button17);`